# Issue installing PHP with IMAP/Kerberos support on Ubuntu 11

Tags: php, ubuntu, imap, kerberos

I'm trying to install PHP on Ubuntu 11.04. I'm compiling from source.

Here is me installing dependencies:

```
apt-get -y install php5-dev php-pear
apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libevent-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgd2-xpm-dev libmcrypt-dev memcached libmemcached-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev
```

And here is my configure script:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --enable-cli --with-fpm-user=php-fpm --with-fpm-group=php-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php --exec-prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/etc --enable-bcmath --enable-ctype --with-curl --with-curlwrappers --enable-dba --with-cdb --with-flatfile --with-inifile --enable-exif --enable-ftp --disable-fileinfo --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl --enable-mbstring=all --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-pspell --enable-shmop --enable-simplexml --with-snmp --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-tidy --enable-wddx --enable-xmlreader --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --with-zip --with-zlib --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm
```

However, I get an error:

```
configure: error: Kerberos libraries not found.

  Check the path given to --with-kerberos (if no path is given, searches in /usr/kerberos, /usr/local and /usr )
```

I didn't provide a path, but there's no directory like /usr/kerberos on my system. About five lines above the error there is a log entry that says `checking for IMAP Kerberos support... yes`.

Do I need to specify a directory for `--with-kerberos` and what would this directory be exactly? I've been on this all day, and can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I was able to sort this issue out with a symbolic link.

Below is the what you do before you run the configure command.

```
mkdir /usr/kerberos
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/kerberos/lib
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue installing PHP 5.3.8 from source on Ubuntu 11.04. I was using:

```
./configure '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-curl' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-kerberos' '--with-mhash=shared' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--with-zlib-dir' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mysqli' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--with-openssl' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-spl' '--enable-tokenizer' '--enable-wddx' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache/conf'
```

and was getting the same error:

```
configure: error: Kerberos libraries not found.
```

Check the path given to --with-kerberos (if no path is given, searches in /usr/kerberos, /usr/local and /usr )

I realized that my kerberos installation files were in the very different /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I tried the suggested "--with-kerberos=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" but as one of the linked pages suggests, the search automatically adds "lib" to the end of the provided path.

As mentioned, one of the other pages linked to here discusses that the script automatically adds "lib" onto the paths (so without specifying a path, it looks in /usr/kerberos/lib, /usr/local/lib, and /usr/lib) but what I failed to realize is that if you're using "--with-libdir=lib64" this results in the script actually looking for /usr/kerberos/lib64, /usr/local/lib64, /usr/lib64).

Upon realizing this, I just created the following symlinks and tried again without specifying a kerberos path.

```
mkdir -p /lib/kerberos
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/kerberos/lib
ln -s /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/kerberos/lib64
```

This worked for me. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. I actually sorted out the issue a while back and forgot to update this. I'll do that now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Googling your error message? **[This page](http://www.sauers.com/blog/technology-and-car-doors/)** seems to have a viable solution to your problem.

" I checked my system, and found that the Kerberos libraries were installed in `/usr/lib64`. So I passed `–with-kerberos=/usr/lib64` to the configure script, but the script still reported that the Kerberos libraries could not be found. "

" From the pages of output that filled my terminal, I found that the configure script was appending **“lib”** to the `–with-kerberos` path that I provided, so it was looking inside a non-existent “/usr/lib64/lib” directory. However, I found that I could change **“lib”** to **“lib64″** by passing `–with-libdir=lib64` to the configure script. "

Comment: Yes, I've been on that particular page (after multiple googles) and tried the suggestions but it didn't work. I tried /usr/lib64, /usr/lib, /usr/include, /usr/include/krb5, and one or two others but it didn't work. I'm not sure what the issue is at this point.

Comment: Did you try `–-with-kerberos` instead of `–with-kerberos`? I'm not sure if that's a typo on the page or not. Does the "Check the path given to --with-kerberos" error go away when you call the script with one of these options? Also, where are your kerberos libraries installed? You can do dpkg -L packageName to query the locations of files belonging to a package. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Ok, by "It didn't work" it means I get the same error when I compile and I'm still where I am. -with-kerberos is a typo, I actually have it as --with-kerberos. I get the error regardless i.e. whether I supply the directory or not. I tried `dpkg -L kerberos` and I get a message saying "Package kerberos is not installed". Does this mean I need to install it, and do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Well you need to specify the exact package name when you do `dpkg -L`. To get a list of packages installed, you can use `dpkg -l` (lower-case l). `man dpkg` for more information. Kerberos packages are usually have "krb" in the name, so you can run `dpkg -l "*krb*"`. The package you probably want to get file locations for is libkrb5-dev, which it looks like you installed in your first command, but we want to know exactly where it's installed instead of just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I really appreciate it. I did `dpkg -L libkrb5-dev` and it gives me a long list of files across a number of directories including /usr/lib, /usr/bin, usr/include, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. Is there a specific file or directory I should be looking for?

Comment: My bets would be on the directory that contains the .so (shared object) files. After you figure that out, can you paste the command that you're trying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3672/discussion-between-anson-and-chuck-ugwuh)

Answer (score 0):

As i had this error with 10.04 as well, I decided to paste my solution as well. Maybe it can help someone someday. Running the compilation on lucid I changed from `--with-kerberos`to `with-kerberos=shared,/usr/lib`. Looks like this was all the magic here as the compiler ran through lib64 missing out on that one.